# Is it possible for an Oracle user without access to a tablespace to insert values into a table placed in this tablespace?

Tags: oracle11g, tablespace

I revoked a user's access to a tablespace.

I thought that this user wouldn't acomplish to insert data in tables from this tablespace. But this user still can.

Is this the normal behaviour or am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: So, I found this. This user has no access to the table space but he has a role assigned to him that let's him insert data in this table. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes, it is "normal."